# How to scrape from XHR in Chrome ( Python )

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape information from the facebook game "Coin Master"

**Inspect Element > Network > XHR**

This brings up "Balance" which i need to access since it contains the information i need to track

[Picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjVjc.png)

[Coin Master FB Link to Test](https://apps.facebook.com/coin-master/?fb_source=bookmark&ref=bookmarks&count=1&fb_bmpos=_1)

But I do not know what module I need to achieve this. I've used BeautifulSoup, Requests in the past but this isn't as straight forward for me.

Any help/insight to my issue would be much appreciated!

Thanks & kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inspect the requests and under Form data find your data for the requests.

```
import requests
import json

data = {
  "Device[udid]": "",
  "API_KEY": "",
  "API_SECRET": "",
  "Device[change]": "",
  "fbToken": ""
}

headers = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36"
}

url = "https://vik-game.moonactive.net/api/v1/users/rof4__cjsvfw2s604xrw1lg5ex42qwc/balance"

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
data = r.json()

print(data["coins"])
```